# Prove that there $B : H\to H $ bounded such $ B^n = A $.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Let $ A : H\to H $ a compact self-adjoint operator. Suppose $ A $ is positive. let $ n \geq 2 $. Prove that there is $B : H\to H $ bounded such $ B^n = A $.

Comment: I think that instead of "limited" you want to say "bounded". Actually $B$ will turn out to be compact, too.

Answer (score 4):

By the Spectral Theorem, $A$ is of the form
$$
A=\sum_j\lambda_j\,P_j,
$$
where $\lambda_j\in\mathbb R$ and $P_j$ is a finite-rank projection for all $j$.

Now choose numbers $\mu_j\in\mathbb C$ with $\mu_j^n=\lambda_j$ and define
$$
B=\sum_j\mu_jP_j.
$$

Comment: Incidentally, by using an appropriate version of the spectral theorem, you can drop the assumption that $A$ is compact.